# Tags on aw blog from a specific category in Magento 1.7

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I have many categories which are created in AW BLOG. One category has many articles. What I need to do is in every article - maybe on the left hand side, show all the tags that are available in all the article from that particular category.

I would GREATLY appreciate any pointers.

Thank you,

Julian